# Bug on a rotating plate problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force, coriolis-effect

A bug is on the edge of a rotating plate, rotating with angular velocity 0.2 rad/s. The bug decides to move towards the centre of the disc, and moves with a velocity v0=0.1m/s from its point of view. The radius of the plate is 1m.
How much time does the bug take to reach the centre?
What does the trajectory of the bug look like to an observer? Use polar coordinates to describe the curve.

The bug now moves in a straight line relative to the observer, and heads towards the center once more. How long does it take to do that?

I have attempted to introduce inertial time-dependent coordinate system xI = xcoswt - ysinwt; yI = xsinwt + ycoswt in the plane of the plate, but I am unsure where to proceed from there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: do provide some information or a pic of your calculations for better help from SE. Do be clear in your question.

Comment: Since the OP specifies the motion without any consideration of the forces involved, are the 2nd, 4th and 5th tags appropriate?

Comment: @Noble Gas Xenon did you get the answer if yes please do post it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no external torque, angular momentum would be conserved. The moment of inertia will first decrease till the bug moves an infinitesimal distance AC( breaking down the curve into many lines) and eventually keep decreasing as it moves towards the centre.
If R is the radius of the plate, m is the mass of the bug, M is the mass of the disc.

Moment of inertia at the edge point, A is
$$I_{1}=mR^{2}+\frac{MR^2}{2}$$
and moment of inertia when it is at a point B( now AB is the tangent to a part of the curve)
$$I_{2}=mr^{2}+\frac{MR^{2}}{2}$$
Here 
$$r^{2}= a^{2}+[\sqrt{R^{2}-a^{2}}-vt]^{2}$$
Where $vt$ is the distance AB
From conservation of angular momentum we see,
$$\omega_{0}I_{1}=\omega(t)I_{2}$$
If you do the same for all points ultimately we observe that the angular velocity near the centre would be nonlinear.
Hence
$$\omega(t)=[\frac{2mr}{MR}]^2-\frac{2mr^{2}}{MR^2}+\frac{2m}{M}-1$$
Now if you obtain the time period and then substitute in the general curve equation you would obtain the solution for time.

Comment: I can't decide if the _op_ means to consider the mass of the plate as $\gg$ the mass of the bug.

Comment: @ja72 yes I agree. The op must provide information about the mass of the bug and the platform.

Comment: I apologise for the inconvenience, but no information about mass was given in the question itself..